# While-Programm Composition & Example

Tags: loops

I've just learned While-Programms. In case you're not familiar with it, a W-P is inductively defined as...

- $x_i \leftarrow x_j+c$  (Addition for every $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$)
- $x_i \leftarrow x_j-c$  (modified subtraction for every $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$)
- If $P_1, P_2$ are While-Programms, so is their composition
- If $P$ is a W-P, so is WHILE $x_i \neq 0$ DO $P$ END for every $i$

I'd like to know what exactly "composition" means in this context. Does it mean a W-P **in** a W-P or one W-P after another W-P? (Or something different?)

Also, I'd like to know how to do following task as a While-Programm...

> If $x_i=c$, then $P$ else $Q$ END; $c\in \mathbb{Z}$

I'd do it like that (see below) but I'm not really sure if I used the right notation. Maybe someone can help me out there.

---

WHILE 1 DO

WHILE $x_i = c$ DO
$P$
END

WHILE $x_i \neq c$ DO $Q$ END

END

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  This could be asked as two separate posts.